# Is it possible to add Grails MVC classes at deployment time?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm writing a Grails app which I'd like 3rd parties to augment at runtime.  Ideally they would be able to add a JAR/WAR to the webapp directory which contains new domain, controller and service classes, new views, and other content.

Is there a simple way to do this within grails?  Would it be simplest to create a startup script which copies the new classes etc. into the relevant directories and then updates grails.xml and web.xml?

Comment: Hello Alison, I'm a bit unclear what you are asking. Would you give a brief concrete example on what you are looking for?

Comment: hi Steve, one example would be: I have made a grails app which allows user account management and login.  Someone else deploys this, but would then like to add inter-user messaging to the original app.  Ideally they could go to a website, download the new functionality (created by a 3rd party) as a JAR/WAR/whatever, drop it in a folder on their webserver and then restart.  The web app now has the new inter-user messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to do this in version 2 of grails in which plugins will be also OSGI plugins http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS/fixforversion/15421

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Grails plugins will actually fit quite well for this: http://www.grails.org/Understanding+Plugins

> A plugin can do just about anything...  One thing a plugin cannot do though is modify the web-app/WEB-INF/web.xml or web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml files. A plugin can participate in web.xml generation, but not modify the file or provide a replacement. A plugin can NEVER change the applicationContext.xml file, but can provide runtime bean definitions